# How to reserve spaces in front of a double using printf() formatting in C

Tags: c++, c, formatting, printf, double

Consider the code, in the C programming language:

```
double d = 3.4;
printf("%02.2f", d);
```

or

```
double d = 3.4;
printf("%2.2f", d);
```

The output you get when running these blocks of code are:

```
3.40
```

I am trying to format a table and need to reserve spaces in front of a double or float so that my tables doesn't draw askew.

What is the best way to obtain the output

```
03.40
```

as intended?

Comment: sprintf to a string, get the length, and pass that to the table drawer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
double d = 3.4;
printf("%05.2f", d);
```

The width field is for the entire converted string (not just the whole number part).

Answer (score 0):

`03.40` does not seem to be a good solution. You should add either leading or trailing spaces, not zeroes.

The best option would be to use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

```
const size_t buffer_size = 16;

double value = 3.40;
char buffer[buffer_size];
int result = snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, "%.2f", value);

if(result > 0 && result < buffer_size)
    printf("Length of string: %d (%s)\n", result, buffer);
```

Output:

```
Length of string: 4 (3.40)
```

Try this code here: [link](https://ideone.com/nwJ5k8).

Oh, one more thing: `snprintf` is a C++ 11 feature. If you doesn't have access to a C++11-compliant compiler, either use less safer version, [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), or use platform-specific solution like [sprintf_s in case of Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx).